# I get an error when i try to update YouTube-dl in 18.04

Tags: youtube-dl

When I type `youtube-dl -U`, I get this error:

```
youtube-dl: error: youtube-dl's self-update mechanism is disabled on Debian.
Please update youtube-dl using apt(8).
See https://packages.debian.org/sid/youtube-dl for the latest packaged version.
```

Comment: You could try `pip install update youtube-dl` if you don't want to wait for someone to package it & grab the updates via normal `apt` means.  The message listed is put in from upstream; removing (*inc. changing*) it would mean more testing....

Comment: sudo: pip: command not found
that's what i got !

Comment: `sudo apt install python-pip` then.   `pip` is the python package manager; youtube-dl is python...

Answer (score 9):

If you want/need the latest `youtube-dl` (and can't wait for it to be packaged & installed via debian/ubuntu .deb)

`pip install update youtube-dl`

`pip` is the package management tool for python (the language that youtube-dl is written in).

[ If you haven't `pip` installed; you can install it with `sudo apt install python-pip`]

Comment: I'll add, rather than risk having two versions installed (and potential conflicts, ie.  *deb* packaged version **and** the `pip` installed version as well) I would suggest removing the *deb* packaged version first, then installing the python installed version of `youtube-dl`.